# How to calculate product of columns followed by sum over all columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Table 1 --Spark DataFrame table

[image]

There is a column called "productMe" in Table 1; and there are also other columns like a, b, c and so on whose schema name is contained in a schema array T.

What I want is the inner product of columns(product each row of the two columns) in schema array T with the column productMe(Table 2). And sum each column of Table 2 to get Table 3.

Table 2 is not necessary if you have good idea to get Table 3 in one step.

Table 2  -- Inner product table

[image]

For example, the column "a·productMe" is (3*0.2, 6*0.6, 5*0.4) to get (0.6, 3.6, 2)

Table 3 -- sum table

[image]

For example, the column "sum(a·productMe)" is 0.6+3.6+2=6.2.

Table 1 is DataFrame of Spark, how can I get Table 3?

Comment: I do not know the name of a, b, c and the number of the column is unknown. The name a, b,c etc are contained in the schema array T.

Comment: Please stop posting snapshots of your data and enter actual values ! Also show some efforts in doing your "assignment" !

Comment: this is a useful question to me whether or not it is an “assignment”. I have need of a solution for work and I don’t have time for “homework.”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like the following :

```
val df = Seq(
  (3,0.2,0.5,0.4),
  (6,0.6,0.3,0.1),
  (5,0.4,0.6,0.5)).toDF("productMe", "a", "b", "c")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val columnsToSum = df.
  columns.  // <-- grab all the columns by their name
  tail.     // <-- skip productMe
  map(col). // <-- create Column objects
  map(c => round(sum(c * col("productMe")), 3).as(s"sum_${c}_productMe"))
val df2 = df.select(columnsToSum: _*)
df2.show()
# +---------------+---------------+---------------+
# |sum_a_productMe|sum_b_productMe|sum_c_productMe|
# +---------------+---------------+---------------+
# |            6.2|            6.3|            4.3|
# +---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The trick is to use `df.select(columnsToSum: _*)` which means that you want to select all the columns on which we did the sum of columns times the `productMe` column. The `:_*` is a Scala-specific syntax to specify that we are passing repeated arguments because we don't have a fix number of arguments.

Comment: That was a smart solution. One question though. Isn't your map function going to create OOM as you suggested for my approach?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan That won't be a problem here because we aggregate once.

Comment: DataFrames are immutable collections. Thus you'll need to assign the transformation results to a new DataFrame value. I have updated my answer to make it easier for you to understand.

Answer (score 3):

We can do it with simple SparkSql

```
   val table1 = Seq(
   (3,0.2,0.5,0.4),
   (6,0.6,0.3,0.1),
   (5,0.4,0.6,0.5)
 ).toDF("productMe", "a", "b", "c")

table1.show
table1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1") 

val table2 = spark.sql("select a*productMe, b*productMe, c*productMe  from table1")   //spark is sparkSession here
table2.show

val table3 = spark.sql("select sum(a*productMe), sum(b*productMe), sum(c*productMe) from table1")
table3.show
```

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers use `sum` aggregation that use `groupBy` under the covers.

`groupBy` always introduces a shuffle stage and usually (*always?*) is slower than corresponding window aggregates.

In this particular case, I also believe that window aggregates give better performance as you can see in their physical plans and details for their only one job.

### CAUTION

Either solution uses one single partition to do the calculation that in turn makes them **unsuitable** for large datasets as their size together may easily exceed the memory size of a single JVM.

### Window Aggregates

What follows is a window aggregate-based calculation which, in this particular case where we group over all the rows in a dataset, unfortunately gives the same physical plan. That makes my answer just a (hopefully) nice learning experience.

```
val df = Seq(
  (3,0.2,0.5,0.4),
  (6,0.6,0.3,0.1),
  (5,0.4,0.6,0.5)).toDF("productMe", "a", "b", "c")

// yes, I did borrow this trick with columns from @eliasah's answer
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val columns = df.columns.tail.map(col).map(c => c * col("productMe") as s"${c}_productMe")
val multiplies = df.select(columns: _*)
scala> multiplies.show
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|       a_productMe|       b_productMe|       c_productMe|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|0.6000000000000001|               1.5|1.2000000000000002|
|3.5999999999999996|1.7999999999999998|0.6000000000000001|
|               2.0|               3.0|               2.5|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+

def sumOverRows(name: String) = sum(name) over ()
val multipliesCols = multiplies.
  columns.
  map(c => sumOverRows(c) as s"sum_${c}")
val answer = multiplies.
  select(multipliesCols: _*).
  limit(1)  // <-- don't use distinct or dropDuplicates here
scala> answer.show
+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
|  sum_a_productMe|sum_b_productMe|  sum_c_productMe|
+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
|6.199999999999999|            6.3|4.300000000000001|
+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

### Physical Plan

Let's see the physical plan then (as it was the only reason why we wanted to see how to do the query using window aggregates, wasn't it?)

[image]

The following is the details for the only job 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then following can be your solution

```
   val df = Seq(
       (3,0.2,0.5,0.4),
       (6,0.6,0.3,0.1),
       (5,0.4,0.6,0.5)
     ).toDF("productMe", "a", "b", "c")
```

This gives input dataframe as you have (you can add more)

```
+---------+---+---+---+
|productMe|a  |b  |c  |
+---------+---+---+---+
|3        |0.2|0.5|0.4|
|6        |0.6|0.3|0.1|
|5        |0.4|0.6|0.5|
+---------+---+---+---+
```

And

```
val productMe = df.columns.head
val colNames = df.columns.tail
var tempdf = df
for(column <- colNames){
  tempdf = tempdf.withColumn(column, col(column)*col(productMe))
}
```

Above steps should give you Table2

```
+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|productMe|a                 |b                 |c                 |
+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|3        |0.6000000000000001|1.5               |1.2000000000000002|
|6        |3.5999999999999996|1.7999999999999998|0.6000000000000001|
|5        |2.0               |3.0               |2.5               |
+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Table3 can be achieved as following

```
tempdf.select(sum("a").as("sum(a.productMe)"), sum("b").as("sum(b.productMe)"), sum("c").as("sum(c.productMe)")).show(false)
```

Table3 is

```
+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|sum(a.productMe) |sum(b.productMe)|sum(c.productMe) |
+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|6.199999999999999|6.3             |4.300000000000001|
+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Table2 can be achieved for any number of columns you have but Table3 would require you to define columns explicitly

Comment: Iterating to add columns on a spark dataframe is a bad practice as it makes the linear longer and subject of causing OOME.

Comment: @eliasah can you help me understand where the above approach is generating longer linearity?